# Dash dcc.Dropdown issue with clear all

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, plotly-dash

So, I have this very simplified Dash app example. Code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import plotly.express as px
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

data = {'Fruits': ['apple',  'orange',  'banana'], 'Number': [10, 15, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Fruits', 'Number'])
fruits_options = df['Fruits']

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Fruits Bar Chart'),
    html.Div([
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='dropdown',
            options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in fruits_options],
            value='All Fruits',
            multi=True
         ),
        html.Div(dcc.Graph(id='graph')),
    ]),
])


@app.callback(
   Output(component_id='graph', component_property='figure'),
   Input(component_id='dropdown', component_property='value')
)
def update_graph(fruits):
    if 'All Fruits' in fruits:
        dff = df.copy()
    else:
        dff = df[df['Fruits'].isin(fruits)]

    figure = px.bar(dff, x=dff['Fruits'], y=dff['Number'])

    return figure


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

User can select multiple options and they will appear on the chart but when the user chose to `clear all` (x on the right side) it shows this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot accept list of column references or list of columns for both `x` and `y`.
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this?
Also, If possible I would like to return to the initial state of the chart when clear all is selected.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remove the error, you need to handle the case where `fruits` is an empty list. It could be as simple as replacing the

```
'All Fruits' in fruits
```

condition by

```
not fruits or 'All Fruits' in fruits
```

Since `not fruits` evaluates to `True` when the `fruits` variable is an empty list and your initial state was `'All Fruits'`, this simple change should yield the desired outcome.

Comment: Perfect, it works! Thanks so much for the quick answer.